# Error handling of executed slice of functions in Go

Tags: go

I must run an unknown number of functions in a for cycle and I want to create meaningful errors when something goes wrong (when error returns from one of them)

Here some code:

```
package storage

import (
    "github.com/attilasatan/ankara/engine/indexer"
)

type NewHandler func(*indexer.Document) error

var NewHandlers []NewHandler


func AppendNewHandler(handler NewHandler) {
    NewHandlers = append(NewHandlers, handler)
}


func New(document *indexer.Document) (err error) {
    for i, handler := range NewHandlers {
        err = handler(document)
        if err != nil {
            err = errors.New(`New Handler error at index ` + string(i) + `
            original: 
            ` + err.Error())
            return
        }
    }
    return
}
```

This is my solution for error handling but i don't feel comfortable with it because I only return the index of the function that I executed.

My question is. Can I collect more information about the function that returned not nil `error`.

Also any kind of advises would be appreciated.

Comment: What information do you want? Can the functions return better errors? Can you use something like: https://godoc.org/github.com/pkg/errors?

Comment: You can do whatever you want. error is an interface, so you can put any data you want into it.

Comment: @JimB Anything that make same ease at debuging an error. I mean for example can I find the source file of function which returned not nil error. This could sounds like silly to you but if I can it could really helpful while debuging.

Comment: It sounds like the problem is more that the handler functions aren't returning sufficiently useful errors. If the handlers return good error messages, you shouldn't need to add much (if any) context to them.

Comment: @Lupus: you can't tell the path that the error value has taken after execution, context has to be added at the error site.

Comment: @Adrian The problem is I do not have full control on handler functions. This going to be a public API which handler functions are optional add-ons to main package. They are going to be located in third persons' packages. I only place restrictions over interfaces and types. I can't force them to return useful errors.

Comment: But it's in their own best interest to do so, if they want to be able to troubleshoot their own handlers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a struct that contains the func and any metadata instead of just a func. Something like this.

```
type NewHandler struct {
    Handler func(*indexer.Document) error
    Data string // or whatever data
}
```

Also make sure your slice holds pointers because go is pass-by-value.

```
var NewHandlers []*NewHandler
```

Then when you for loop, it goes like this.

```
for i, handler := range NewHandlers {
        err = handler.Handler(document)
        ....
```

And you can include your Data in the error.